# Transpose rows, columns, and groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a DF that I want to transpose rows and columns and group (distinct count) the number of ID's. My example:

```
ID<- c(111,222,111,222,333,111,222,333)
AGE_GROUP<- c("30_40","30_40","30_40","30_40","50_60","30_40","30_40","50_60")
DATE<-c("JAN","JAN","FEB","FEB","FEB","MAR","MAR","MAR")
DF<-data.frame(ID,AGE_GROUP,DATE)
```

The result I wish to have.My new DF:

```
AGE_GROUP<- c("30_40","50_60")
JAN<- c(2,0)
FEB<- c(2,1)
MAR<- c(2,1)
DF2<-data.frame(AGE_GROUP,JAN,FEB,MAR)
```

How would I do this grouping and transposition?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/62439791/5325862

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use `pivot_wider` with `values_fn` after removing the 'ID' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF %>% 
  select(-ID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = DATE, values_from = DATE, 
     values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#  AGE_GROUP   JAN   FEB   MAR
#  <chr>     <int> <int> <int>
#1 30_40         2     2     2
#2 50_60         0     1     1
```

---

In `base R`, `table` would be easier

```
table(DF[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks, worked here! Did you simply consider the occurrence count? What if it were the distinct occurrence count?

Comment: @BrunoAvila it is simply the count.  If you need unique then use `table(unique(DF[-1]))`