# Counting number of values based on conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm new to R and have a dataset of historical economic calendar events like this:

```
Date, Currency
01/03/2017 15:00:00,USD
01/03/2017 15:00:00,USD
01/04/2017 10:00:00,EUR
01/04/2017 10:00:00,EUR
01/04/2017 19:00:00,USD
01/06/2017 13:30:00,USD
01/06/2017 13:30:00,USD
01/06/2017 13:30:00,USD
```

And from this, I want to count how many EUR events there are per date and then also count the number of USD events per date (Ignoring time).

The final data frame should look like this:

```
Date, EUR, USD
01/03/2017, 0, 2
01/04/2017, 2, 1
01/06/2017, 0, 3
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Drop the time component, count by date and currency, then reshape to wide format. e.g. with dplyr & tidyr. There should be a lot of posts on SO already about grouping, summarizing, and pivoting, such as https://stackoverflow.com/q/62439791/5325862

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
your_data %>%
    group_by(Date) %>%
    count(Currency) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = Currency, 
        names_glue = '{.value.count}',
        values_from = n
        )
```

Comment: Thats good but how do I then move it so that the "Date" is the index and the other two columns are "EUR.Count" and "USD.Count"?

Comment: Updated the answer. For pivoting data you should see:
`library(tidyr)`
`vignette('pivot')`

Answer (score 0):

After extracting the date you can do this with `pivot_wider`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(lubridate::mdy_hms(Date))) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Currency, values_from = Currency, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#  Date         USD   EUR
#  <date>     <int> <int>
#1 2017-01-03     2     0
#2 2017-01-04     1     2
#3 2017-01-06     3     0
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, the `dcast()` function can be used to reshape and count in one step:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(events[, Date := anytime::anydate(Date)], 
      Date ~ paste0(Currency, ".count"), length)
```

> ```
>          Date EUR.count USD.count
> 1: 2017-01-03         0         2
> 2: 2017-01-04         2         1
> 3: 2017-01-06         0         3
> ```

Here, `anydate()` is used to coerce the character time stamps to class `Date`.

Also note that the currency columns have been renamed as [requested by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68131514/counting-number-of-values-based-on-conditions-in-r#comment120417549_68131650).

#### Data

```
library(data.table)
events <- fread("Date, Currency
01/03/2017 15:00:00,USD
01/03/2017 15:00:00,USD
01/04/2017 10:00:00,EUR
01/04/2017 10:00:00,EUR
01/04/2017 19:00:00,USD
01/06/2017 13:30:00,USD
01/06/2017 13:30:00,USD
01/06/2017 13:30:00,USD")
```