# Pivot_wider and count number of occurrences retaining all other columns

Tags: r, tidyr

I want to `pivot_wider` to spread the column `issue`. The value should be the number of occurences of each `issue` per `product`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(product=  c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                type = c(rep("a",3),rep("b", 3),rep("a",3)),
                issue = c("fall","fall","trap",
                          "trap", "jump", "fall",
                          "trap", "jump", "open"))
```

Output should be

```
  product type fall trap jump open
1       1    a    2    1   NA   NA
2       2    b    1    1    1   NA
3       3    a   NA    1    1    1
```

I have tried the answer provided here: [pivot_wider, count number of occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439791/pivot-wider-count-number-of-occurrences) but this does not retain other columns:

```
df%>%
  group_by(product)%>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = "product", names_from = "issue", values_from = type, values_fn = list(type = length))


 product  fall  trap  jump  open
    <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1       1     2     1    NA    NA
2       2     1     1     1    NA
3       3    NA     1     1     1
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can count them first:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df = data.frame(product=  c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                type = c(rep("a",3),rep("b", 3),rep("a",3)),
                issue = c("fall","fall","trap",
                          "trap", "jump", "fall",
                          "trap", "jump", "open"))
df %>% 
  count(product, type, issue) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = issue,
              values_from = n)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 6
#>   product type   fall  trap  jump  open
#>     <dbl> <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1       1 a         2     1    NA    NA
#> 2       2 b         1     1     1    NA
#> 3       3 a        NA     1     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That's great, thanks. Even better: `df%>%count(across(everything()))...`